How in PhpStorm 2024.1 to make Sticky lines marker better visible?
Sticky lines in PhpStorm 2024.1 seems interesting feature, but trying work with it I would like :
To make Sticky lines more visible and distinct, as I can hardly see it :

also if there is a way to switch Sticky linesmode with hot key ?
